# Network timeout..cannot pull images

Tags: docker

My current operating system is Windows 10 and 
I have installed Virtual Box and then added an Ubuntu VM on top of that. I installed the docker-engine on Ubuntu and I added the insecure-registry.
But when I am trying to pull the images..it always says "Network timed out error". I have tried most of the suggestions from Google, but to no success.
I cannot even pull images from public DockerHub like docker pull hello-world

Please do help me .

I am doing the commands in the following order

```
sudo docker pull hello-world
```

output:

```
using default tag : latest
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world
Network timed out while trying to connect to https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/lirary/hello-world/iamges. You may want to check your internet connection or if you are behind proxy.
```

My admin team confirms that we are not using any proxies in the company.

Few more details

- Operating System : Windows 10
- Virtual Box : 5.1.2
- VM : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Docker : 1.11.2

I am struggling with this not sure what is happening..Please help me.

Thanks and appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Have you tried to access the repository from the shell? With wget or something similar? My first idea regarding your problem is, that your ubuntu vm network isn't correctly setup.

Comment: It seems a network issue in your ubuntu VM, Have you internet access from that VM?

Comment: @ReneM. Yes I am able to pull the image if I use the command wget, only if I do docker pull or run it says network timeout.

Comment: @cml.co yes I do have internet access on that machine as I am able to browse and also from terminal able to ping the addresses

Comment: How did you do this?  " ... added the insecure-registry"

Comment: @cml.co yes I did add an insecure registry for my local repositories..but hello-world is from public dockerhub and nothing works.

Comment: Can you show the logs of your vm (when you're trying to pull the image and it fails) + sudo service docker status

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
For me it was a network problem in VirtualBox. I configures network 'Adapter 1' as the following (attached to-> NAT and Port Forwarding (name:ssh,Protocol:TCP,Host IP: 127.0.0.1, Host Port:22, Guest IP:,Guest Protocol:22)).

I hope it helps, regards!